# Expected a value of type 'Widget', but got one of type 'Null'

Tags: dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, dart-pub, dart-null-safety

i am learning responsive web but i am stuck here in some kind of error like

> Expected a value of type 'Widget', but got one of type 'Null'

don't know how to fix this error i tried a lot but i think i can't solve this without someone's help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const int largeScreenSize = 1366;
const int mediumScreenSize = 768;
const int smallScreenSize = 360;
const int customScreenSize = 1100;

class Responsiveness extends StatelessWidget {
   final Widget? largeScreen;
   final Widget? mediumScreen;
   final Widget? smallScreen;

   const Responsiveness({
    this.largeScreen,
    this.mediumScreen,
    this.smallScreen,
  });

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
       double _width = constraints.maxWidth;
        if (_width >= largeScreenSize) {
         return largeScreen as Widget;
       } else if (_width >= mediumScreenSize && _width < largeScreenSize) {
         return mediumScreen ?? largeScreen as Widget;
       } else {
         return smallScreen ?? largeScreen as Widget;
       }
     });
   }
 }
```

Comment: Are you providing the three fields to the constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`largeScreen`, `mediumScreen` and `smallScreen` all have the type `Widget?`, meaning: "either a `Widget` or `null`.

When you return `largeScreen as Widget`, if `largeScreen` is null, you will get an error, because `null` is not a valid value for `Widget` (just like `123 as String` would throw, since the types are not assignable).

Looking at your code, if all 3 of those variables are `null`, you'd eventually try to return `null` from the `LayoutBuilder` parameter, which is always an error, because it returns a non-null `Widget`.

Make sure you account for the case where all of these are `null`, or make sure they are never all null at the same time (perhaps with an `assert` statement).

Comment: thanks man it worked i get it what are you saying.